# Performance tests for Lightweight Encryption

Tags: cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I am currently doing my final project, and I need to conduct some performance tests on at least 3 lightweight encryption algorithms (symmetric block ciphers).  Ideally encrypt/decrypt of a text file and measure/compare at least 3 metrics such as execution time, memory, code size, throughput. I'm struggling to work out how to achieve this so if anyone has any pointers I would be extremely grateful. I've no experience with code although I'm trying to work this out (looking at C#, Java Cryptographic Extension, FELICS). 
Thanks.

Comment: According to [ask] this is an opinion based question. could  you rephrase it a bit?

Comment: Please explain what part you're struggling with.

Comment: You do not define "lightweight".  You could, for example, write your own simple Feistel cipher as a "lightweight" cipher.  RC4 is probably a lightweight cipher, though it is a stream cipher, not a block cipher.

Answer (score 0):

Consider constructing speed and memory tests of one-time pad, as an example of perfect secrecy or a substitution cipher perhaps, DES as an outdated form of symmetric encryption, and it’s modern replacement AES. Pick a language, and duckduckgo for library implementations of the latter two.